# Haskell: How to generate a cartesian product of two simple algebraic data types

Tags: haskell, cartesian-product, algebraic-data-types

I am learning Haskell, so I'm writing some simple card games. I've defined some data types:

```
data Rank = Ace|Two|Three|Four|Five|Six|Seven|Eight|Nine|Ten|Jack|Queen|King deriving (Eq,Show,Ord)

data Suit = Hearts|Spades|Diamonds|Clubs deriving (Show)

data Card = Card Rank Suit
```

Now I'd like to create a pristine deck of 52 cards. I'm sure there is a slick way to do it, but all I can come up with is:

```
 pristineDeck = [Card Ace Hearts, Card Two Hearts, ...]
```

Can I get Haskell to generate this list for me?

Comment: Make your types derive the "Enum" typeclass (it can happen by just putting Enum next to `Show` up there). The three of them: Rank, Suit and Card.

Comment: P.S. what you are looking for is not the cross product, which is something involving 3D vectors. You probably meant "Cartesian product".

Comment: @BenMillwood My bad..."SQL cross join" + "cartesian product" + degree in physics

Comment: @BenMillwood: Better still to play it safe, and be like the mathematicians--just call everything a "product" and rely on context to disambiguate. Maybe call it a "tensor product" if you're feeling generous.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: Do you have a sum? Call it a coproduct instead!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List comprehensions are a very tidy syntax for this. If you derive `Enum` on `Rank` and `Suit` you can express it very simply as:

```
pristineDeck = [ Card rank suit | suit <- [Hearts .. Clubs], rank <- [Ace .. King] ]
```

If you're wondering why I have `suit` and `rank` in different orders, the first is because of the order the `Card` constructor uses, while the latter is to get the order of the resulting list--suits together in ascending order.

In more generality, or when a single list comprehension gets too bulky, the cartesian product is exactly the behavior given by the `Monad` instance for lists. The following is equivalent to the list comprehension above:

```
pristineDeck = do suit <- [Hearts .. Clubs]
                  rank <- [Ace .. King]
                  return $ Card rank suit
```

As one other minor point, to save yourself the trouble of remembering what order the `Suit` values are in, deriving `Bounded` as well will enable to write `[minBound .. maxBound]` to enumerate all values of any type with instances of both `Enum` and `Bounded`.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't derive `Enum` for the `Suit` type, and just write out the full list in the comprehension. Suits don't have a natural ordering, IMO, so the ellipsis-syntax is confusing.

Comment: And I would also derive a `Bounded` instance. `[minBound .. maxBound]` makes it clear that you're enumerating all the variants, even if there's no natural ordering.

Comment: @C.A. McCann Be careful to type `[Hearts .. Clubs]` and `[Ace .. King]`, otherwise you'll get an error: `Not in scope: 'Hearts..'`.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka: Yes, that's my favored solution as well, which is why I was editing it into the answer as you were writing that comment. ;]

Comment: @AlfonsoVillén: Thanks. Stupid lousy no good pain-in-the-neck syntactic corner cases...

Comment: `Card <$> [minBound..maxBound] <*> [minBound..maxBound]`

Comment: @Tinctorius: Yes, though if you want a nicely sorted deck that's probably not ideal.

Comment: @Tinctorius: That would work! But in this case I actually think the list comprehension is more readable. More helpful would be the `enumerate = [minBound .. maxBound]` that I have defined in my tweaked `Prelude`. It's handy for exactly this sort of purpose.

Comment: @BenMillwood: suits do have an order in games like Bridge.

Comment: @siride: yes, but a game like Hearts might have a different ordering. In fact, the same applies to ranks, arguably, so it's a bit of a judgement call. Since the whole list of suits is only four elements anyway, I don't think it hurts too much to just write it out.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to do this, of varying amounts of wizardry.

Firstly, since none of the constructors of your types have arguments, you can derive `Enum` for them. This will allow you to write e.g. `[Ace..King]` to get a list of all cards.

Secondly, list comprehensions are a great way to form a list of items drawn from multiple other lists. Try this:

```
[x + y | x <- [100,200,300], y <- [1,2,3]]
```

That should give you the tools you need to apply to your example.

Answer (score 3):

Alp is correct on tell you to derive Enum

```
>data Rank = Ace|Two|Three|Four|Five|Six|Seven|Eight|Nine|Ten|Jack|Queen|King deriving (Eq,Show,Ord,Enum)
>data Suit = Hearts|Spades|Diamonds|Clubs deriving (Show,Enum)
```

Now:

```
>enumFrom Ace
[Ace,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten,Jack,Queen,King]
```

To get the permutations of two lists you can use a list comprehension:

```
>[[x,y]|x<-[1..2],y<-[2..5]]
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5]]
```

or to get the permutations of addition:

```
>[x + y|x<-[1..2],y<-[2..5]]
[3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7]
```

Now you just need to do a few substitutions to get the permutations of Car with Rank and Suit.